# Identify two PHY Ethernet controllers on MII bus in u-boot, DTS or kernel driver?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, u-boot, device-tree

The issue that I am looking a solution for is that I have to upgrade the Ethernet controller on my motherboard because the component is going obsolete.

The board is running u-boot and kernel 2.6 with a device tree.

I have to mention that the new Ethernet chip is placed on the new motherboard on a different address location than previous:

phy-handle = <&PHY1>; -old address register,

phy-handle = <&PHY0>; -new address register:

dts file:

```
    mdio@e00 {
        compatible = "fsl,mpc885-fec-mdio", "fsl,pq1-fec-mdio";
        reg = <0xe00 0x188>;
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;

        PHY0: ethernet-phy@0 {
            reg = <0x0>;
            device_type = "ethernet-phy";
        };

        PHY1: ethernet-phy@1 {
            reg = <0x1>;
            device_type = "ethernet-phy";
        };

        PHY2: ethernet-phy@2 {
            reg = <0x2>;
            device_type = "ethernet-phy";
        };
```

...

```
    EMAC0: ethernet@1e00 {
        device_type = "network";
        compatible = "fsl,mpc885-fec-enet",
                     "fsl,pq1-fec-enet";
        reg = <0x1e00 0x188>;
   mac-address = [ 00 00 00 00 00 00 ];
        interrupts = <7 1>;
        interrupt-parent = <&PIC>;
        phy-handle = <&PHY0>;
        linux,network-index = <0>;
    };
```

The constrain is that I do not want have 2 separate builds for each board, but a smart piece of code that identifies which Ethernet controller is present on the motherboard.

Now my question is where this identification code should be added?, in u-boot?, in the device tree file?, or in the kernel Ethernet driver?

What I have noticed during the debugging process, is that compared to the kernel that ONLY loads the driver specified by the device tree, the u-boot is smart enough to scan the mii bus and identify the Ethernet controller.

thanks,
regards

Comment: *"I do not want have 2 separate builds for each board"* -- If the only difference is the PHY, then there should be no reason for unique kernels, that's what DT is supposed to resolve.  I have an Atmel eval board that specifies two PHYs (at different addresses) for one EMAC in the DT, and the mii_bus probe during kernel boot only detects the one actual PHY.  See https://github.com/linux4sam/linux-at91/blob/linux-4.1-at91/arch/arm/boot/dts/sama5d3xcm.dtsi  However this is an ARM kernel version much later than 2.6 (PPC?). BTW *"Ethernet controller"* usually refers to the EMAC rather than the PHY.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Yes the only difference between my motherboards is the PHY controller register address.

I am stuck with this 2.6 kernel version, so a solution has to be found within current context.

What would be your understanding about the following device tree EMAC field settings?:

1. EMAC0: ethernet@1e00
2. reg = <0x1e00 0x188>;

Comment: During the debugging process I have tried to DOUBLE the emac structure inside the device tree file where the only difference is the phy-handle...but the kernel doesn't build because of a double memory address error.

Comment: If you only have one EMAC and one of two possible PHYs, then why would you try to define *two* EMACs in the DT?  That does not resemble a (working) example (from Atmel) that I mentioned, that IMO is worth trying.